# Rebuild hhvm on Windows

Tags: c++, c, facebook, hhvm, hiphop

i want rebuild hhvm from source in windows 10(64 bits,type = home).

Source : https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/

Link 1 : github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Building-and-installing-HHVM-on-Windows-with-MSVC

Link 2 : github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Building-and-Installing-HHVM-on-Cygwin

output of `cmake .` or `./configure` is :

```
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:18 (PROJECT):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.



CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:18 (PROJECT):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/hhvm-master/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/hhvm-master/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

i also test `cmake .` comment in `msys 1.0` and `cmd` and `VS2015 x86 x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt` and `VS2013 x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt` and `Developer Command Prompt for VS2013` and `Developer Command Prompt for VS2012` and `VS2012 x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt` and ....

information :

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (i686-posix-dwarf-rev4, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 4.8.2
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


$ g++ --version
g++ (i686-posix-dwarf-rev4, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 4.8.2
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.7.0-rc3
CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

files,folders in `c:\hhvm-master\` dir :

```
$ ls
CMake  CMakeCache.txt  CMakeFiles  CMakeLists.txt  CONTRIBUTING.md  ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md  LICENSE.PHP  LICENSE.ZEND  README.md  configure  deps  hphp  third-party
```

folders in `c:\hhvm-master\deps\` :

```
$ ls
include  lib
```

also Cygwin B20(`C:\cygnus\cygwin-b20\cygnus.bat`)

```
bash-2.02$ cd c:/hhvm-master
bash-2.02$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug .
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:18 (PROJECT):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.



CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:18 (PROJECT):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/hhvm-master/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/hhvm-master/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

How fix problem of cmake?

Answer (score 0):

I've reach to make HHVM work in Nuclide on Windows based on Docker and the Remote Project functionality. You can check my repo in order to make it work you too:

https://github.com/nahuelhds/nuclide-hhvm-windows

You only need to have Docker and then use the docker commands build and run nothing else, really. It's all explained at the repo itself.

I know it's not an exact answer to your question, but maybe you can give it a try.

Hope it works for you.
Regards